# SQL Server Replication Tutorial Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

Working through a tutorial on Transactional Replication on SQL Server 2008 R2 with AdventureWorks. Publisher, Distributor and Subscriber are all in the same instance. I am getting this error...

> Cannot DROP TABLE
>   'Production.ProductModelProductDescriptionCulture'
>   because it is being referenced by
>   object 'vProductAndDescription'.
>   (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number:
>   3729)

I would think that the sample db is replication ready so it's not clear if the issue is in the db, the instance configuration or replication configuration.

Comment: What were you doing that caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am following the Microsoft Press MCTS Certification lesson plan for the setup of basic transactional replication. So far, I made a copy of the database, created a distributor, created a publisher, created a subscriber. Up to this point, everything executes without error. When I launch replication monitor to see what is happening, this error is the first item on the list.